# CSS outline property appearing as two separate line in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using the CSS outline property to create a dashed line. While the line renders correctly in Chrome and Safari, in Firefox it appears as two separate lines. If I carefully adjust the size of the window I can get these two line into perfect alignment so that they appear as a single line, but I should not have to do this.

Chrome CSS outline property:
[image: Chrome outline property]

CSS

```
.dash-border{
        outline-style: dashed;
        outline-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 80px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="dash-border"></div>
```

Comment: They seem to get the same problem in their documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: could you explain more what do you mean by `it appears as two separate lines`? I get the same, normal, result in both Chrome and Mozila

Comment: @Chris I added an image of how the outline renders in chrome, but the image upload feature is acting a little weird so for the example of how it renders in firefox refer to this imgur link, http://imgur.com/a/LU6K7

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `-moz`, for example:

```
.dash-border
{
   outline-style: dashed;
   outline-color: #fff;
   -moz-outline-style:dashed;
   -moz-outline-color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   position:absolute;
   bottom: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Using the -moz prefix doesn't seem to work for those properties. When I inspect the element it list the -moz values for those properties as invalid.

Comment: Deprecated and the support for it has been removed in Firefox 3.6.